# Mysql - How do I identify and select only columns that are different when comparing two entries?

Tags: python, mysql, select, sqlalchemy

My table is set up as follows:

```
ID EVENT Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 ... Value10
1  400   2      2      2      2          2
... 
7  500   3      6      5      5          1
8  200   4      4      4      4          4
9  500   3      7      6      5          1
```

At the point in time when ID 9 is created/inserted, it will be the highest ID in the table. Upon inserting this entry, I want to find the most recent previous entry where the event matches the event for ID 9 (id 7 in this example).  Then select/return only the column(s) where the values are different (in this example, both Value2 and Value3). I don't know which or how many values will be different ahead of time.

Desired output:

```
ID EVENT Value2 Value3
7  500   6      5
9  500   7      6
```

I'm using python/sqlalchemy and I'd like to know if I can do this sort of analysis efficiently using mysql alone for a table with thousands of entries.

Comment: Short answer: with just a query, No. In a stored procedure, Yes.

Comment: What would you like to do with this kind of data after you get it?

Answer (score 0):

For a given query, the number of resulting columns is fixed. It depends only on the schema of your database, but not on the actual data therein. For this reason, you cannot retrieve a subset of columns up front. I suggest you detect relevant columns in Python instead.